# Check existence of file on disk?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Currently I am loading data from a previous session into my application using the code below. To guard against there being no previous data I am using a temp variable to check the return value before making my assignment. I am just posting here as this feels a bit clunky, is there a way to check a file exists on disk so I can check before continuing, or is what I have the way to go?

```
NSMutableArray *artistCollection;
NSMutableArray *artistCollection_LOAD;

artistCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
artistCollection_LOAD = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"/data"];
if(artistCollection_LOAD != nil) artistCollection = artistCollection_LOAD;
else NSLog(@"(*) - Saved Data Not Found");
```

Prior to this I had (see below) but as you can imagine if NSKeyedUnarchiver did not find a file and returned "nil" it trashed my previously allocated array.

```
artistCollection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
artistCollection = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"/data"];
```

gary

Comment: No, your second code snippet *always* leaks the previously-allocated array, because you unconditionally replace the pointer to that array with whatever `unarchivedObjectWithFile:` returned and you don't release the array you created.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cocoa has a class that provides support for dealing with filesystem objects: [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html). You can use a standard file manager (provided by `+defaultManager`) in conjunction with the `-fileExistsAtPath:` method, which returns a `BOOL` value for whether the file exists or not:

```
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/data"]) { /* ... */ }
```

Keep in mind this doesn't tell you anything about whether the file is accessible (permissions-wise), is a directory, etc. There are other NSFileManager functions for those.